# Find hours and minutes (if they are there) with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following potential strings:

Up to 200 h

Up to 13 h 40 min
...

Right now I am able to find the hours with the following regex:

```
/Up to (\d+) h/.match("Up to 200 h")
```

However, for the other kind of entrances, where I can have minutes too, I fail to see how to build the regex.

At the very end I want to have the total duration in minutes, so for:

```
Up to 200 h ---> 200*60
Up to 13 h 40 min ---> 13*60 + 40
```

Comment: in future you should consider holding off awhile before selecting an answer.  Some of us were still working on answers when you applied the checkmark a mere 16 minutes after posting the question.  Also, it's not in your interest because it may discourage others from posting additional answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using optional group (`(...)?`):

```
m = /Up to (\d+) h\b(?: (\d+) min)?/.match('Up to 200 h')
# => #<MatchData "Up to 200 h" 1:"200" 2:nil>
m[1]
# => "200"
m[2]
# => nil
m[1].to_i * 60 + m[2].to_i
# => 12000

m = /Up to (\d+) h\b(?: (\d+) min)?/.match('Up to 13 h 40 min')
# => #<MatchData "Up to 13 h 40 min" 1:"13" 2:"40">
m[1]
# => "13"
m[2]
# => "40"
m[1].to_i * 60 + m[2].to_i
# => 820

m = /Up to (\d+) h\b(?: (\d+) min)?/.match('Up to 3 hippopotamuses')
# => nil
```

Comment: So then I would just need to check how many entrances the match array has, right?

Comment: @HommerSmith, You don't need to check the count. It contains 3 elements if there's match regardless of match of the second group. Just use `m[1].to_i * 60 + m[2].to_i` (`nil.to_i` returns `0`)

Comment: @CarySwoveland, fixed it using word boundary (`\b`). Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

This works (but intentionally does not ensure that the line begins or contains "Up to"):

```
_, h, _, m = s.match(/(?:^|\s)(\d+)\s+h(\s+(\d+)\s+min)?(?:\s|$)/).to_a

s = "Up to 13  h abc"
_, h, _, m = s.match(/(?:^|\s)(\d+)\s+h(\s+(\d+)\s+min)?(?:\s|$)/).to_a
  #=> [" 13  h ", "13", nil, nil]
  # h => "13", m => nil

s = "Time until   13 h 40  min"
_, h, _, m = s.match(/(?:^|\s)(\d+)\s+h(\s+(\d+)\s+min)?(?:\s|$)/).to_a
  # => ["13 h  40  min", "13", "  40  min", "40"]
  # h => "13", m => "40"

s = "I was chased by 3 hippopotamuses"
_, h, _, m = s.match(/(?:^|\s)(\d+)\s+h(\s+(\d+)\s+min)?(?:\s|$)/).to_a
  #=> []
```

- `(?:..)` signifies a non-capture group.  There is one at the beginning and one at the end. The one at the beginning is followed by capture group 1 that captures the first string of digits, `(?:^|\s)(\d+)`.  Those digits must be preceded by either the beginning of the line (`^`) or (`|`) a whitespace character (`\s`).
- The string of digits captured by the first group must be followed by one or more whitespace characters and then the letter `h` (but that is not captured).
- Capture group 2 follows `h`: `(\s+(\d+)\s+min)?`.  Because of the question mark at the end, a capture will be made if possible, but it is not required for the regex to succeed.  This is because minutes may or may not be present.
- This capture group contains capture group 3, `(\d+)`, which captures the minutes value (if capture 2 is made).  The digits must be preceded by at least one whitespace character and be followed by at least one whitespace character, then `"min"`.
- If capture groups 2 and 3 (for minutes) make captures, the non-capture group `(?:\s|$)` requires that `min` be followed by whitespace or the end of the line.
- If capture groups 2 and 3 do not make a capture, `(?:\s|$)` requires that the letter `h` be followed by whitespace or the end of the line.
- `"Time until   13 h 40  min".match(/.../).to_a` returns the array

.

```
#=> ["13 h  40  min", "13", "  40  min", "40"]
```

where "13", "  40  min" and "40" are captured by groups 1, 2 and 3, respectively.  Since we want captures 1 and 3, we set

```
_, h, _, m = s.match(/.../).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use the alternative operator (or) in the regex like this:

```
(\d+ h|\d+ min)
```

Or include seconds like this:

```
(\d+ h|\d+ min|\d+ sec)
```

This is a "global" match, so in ruby you use `.scan()` like so:

```
$m = "Up to 13 h 40 min 5 sec".scan(/(\d+ h|\d+ min|\d+ sec)/)
```

And then just check for m[1], m[2], m[3] using conditionals (if then).

Comment: I suppose there is a question of how much parsing is called for.   For example: `$m = "Up to 13 hiccups".scan(/(\d+ h|\d+ min|\d+ sec)/) => [["13 h"]]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, yes true. I was just providing another alternative answer to the question, however it does depend on possible input, because you're right, "13 hiccups" would, in fact, match in my answer.